# When will Cassandra 5.0 be a stable release?

Tags: cassandra

as I'am considering migrating from 3.x with a wish to have the longest "support" as possible, I was wondering, when will release 5.0 become stable version, suitable for commercial use? Is there any date staged?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This question should really be asked on the user@cassandra.apache.org mailing list, as this site is more for solving database technical problems.

Comment: As Aaron mentioned above plus you need to define what is the definition for "stable release" in your terms? Have you already put [the existing BETA versions of `5.0`](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) to test? What did you notice that is *not* stable there? Could you provide additional details? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I'll deffinitelly ask at mentioned mail. 
By stable I mean "suitable for use in work enviroment," meaning the moment, it stops being BETA. 
Again, thanks a lot

Comment: You could already use the 5.x beta releases as it's stable.

Comment: And, it's available for commercial use, read more at https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/LICENSE.txt

Answer (score 1):

In as much as we (the project) are working on a 12-month release cadence, it is not a hard schedule given the long list of unexpected things that could affect the release.

The first beta release (`5.0-beta1`) went out in early December and there are several tickets which need to be addressed before a release candidate (`5.0-rc*`) can be cut. For details of what's in scope for 5.0 GA (general availability), [view the kanban board here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=593&view=detail) (requires a [Jira account](https://selfserve.apache.org/jira-account.html)).

The next steps are (1) for a release candidate to be voted on by the community, and (2) provided there are no further issues identified in an RC then (3) a GA version is released. Again, it is hard to predict whether this will take days or a few weeks because it depends on when the outstanding tickets are completed by the contributors but know that the project is working hard on getting the release out as quick as possible.

For more info, see [the Cassandra project's Release Cycle](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/tQzjBw). Cheers!